# What is the Google Play Plus One button URL for an app on the playstore

Tags: android, google-play

What is the correct url for the plus one button linking to the app store. The url im currently using is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**package.here**
this url is out of synch entirely with the amount of +1's
there is another which is https://market.android.com/details?id=**package.here**
which seems to keep in synch though im dubious to the actual results it publishes...
dubious as in i tested with 10 of my friends to +1 but none showed up..

am i using the correct url?